# Onde a função está pegando o horário atual?

Tags: java, android, time

Tenho uma função que retorna o horário atual. De onde vem esse valor? Do horário do telefone? Servidor?

Segue a minha função:

```
public static Date getAgora()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: Só um detalhe: se quer a data/hora atual como um `java.util.Date`, não precisa criar um `Calendar`. Usar somente `new Date()` é o suficiente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em primeira instância vem do sistema operacional que controla o horário do momento para todo o sistema. Ele permite que este horário seja mudado de várias formas, por exemplo ser sincronizado com um relógio externo.

Este relógio do sistema operacional é regido pelo sistema de *clock* do hardware, que ao contrário do nome não é exatamente um relógio e sim um sistema de sincronismo de operações. O sistema operacional se vale desse sistema de sincronismo para calcular quanto tempo passou e saber qual é o horário atual.

Este *clock* é responsável por emitir pulsos que dizem que uma operação pode ser realizada, todos componentes do hardware devem proceder o que sabem fazer de acordo com esses pulsos. O pulso depende da velocidade configurada para o equipamento como um todo trabalhar. Esse 2Ghz que você lê nas especificações de hardware significa que haverá 2 bilhões de pulsos por segundo. Se não tivesse isso cada componente operaria de acordo com sua necessidade e capacidade e o sistema ficaria todo confuso. O processador tem um contador de pulsos que pode ser consultado pelo SO.

Então o sistema operacional sabe que depois de haver 2 bilhões de pulsos passou 1 segundo. Claro que ele pode calcular frações disso, mas não pode chegar na precisão de 1 pulso, nem perto disso, porque o próprio cálculo leva vários pulsos. O melhor que ele consegue é algumas centenas de pulsos (na prática nos cenários mais comuns costuma ficar na casa dos milhares).

Justamente por ele não ter um horário atualizado próprio é necessário uma inicialização (pode pegar um dado gravado em algum lugar do hardware) e até sincronização externa. O controle do sistema operacional não é exatamente preciso e a sincronização externa é útil.

Em geral os sistemas de hardware possuem um mecanismo próprio para manter esse controle mesmo quando o equipamento está desligado usando alguma forma de bateria (guarda o último horário conhecido e vai incrementando os pulsos sem precisar estar todo sistema ligado), mas em sistemas que seja garantido que depende de conexão externa isto nem é necessário já que toda inicialização pode sincronizar com a fonte externa (não acho que seja o caso de celulares, não há garantia de rede disponível).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ou seja, mesmo com fuso-horário ele pega o sistema de clock do hardware, certo ? Daí não preciso me preocupar com o fuso-horário, por mais que não seja exatamente preciso.

Comment: Fuso horário nada tem a ver com isso, este é um conceito humano determinado por outros fatores e o jeito exato é determinado pela implementação e configuração do sistema operacional, então a mudança é determinada por software, se o hardware já não tem um horário de verdade, muito menos terá um fuso horário.